# unordered_map initialization with #include

Tags: c++, data-structures

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> mimeMap = {
    #define STR_PAIR(K,V) std::pair<std::string, std::string>(K,V)
    #include "MimeTypes.inc"
};
```

File MimeTypes.inc is like:

```
STR_PAIR("3dm", "x-world/x-3dmf"),
STR_PAIR("3dmf", "x-world/x-3dmf"),
STR_PAIR("a", "application/octet-stream"),
STR_PAIR("aab", "application/x-authorware-bin"),
STR_PAIR("aam", "application/x-authorware-map"),
STR_PAIR("aas", "application/x-authorware-seg"),
STR_PAIR("abc", "text/vnd.abc"),
STR_PAIR("acgi", "text/html"),
STR_PAIR("afl", "video/animaflex"),
STR_PAIR("ai", "application/postscript"),
STR_PAIR("aif", "audio/aiff"),
```

I am very confused. How does this code initialise an `unordered_map`?

Answer (score 10):

`#include` does textual copy-paste. It's almost as if you had written the following directly:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> mimeMap = {
    #define STR_PAIR(K,V) std::pair<std::string, std::string>(K,V)
    STR_PAIR("3dm", "x-world/x-3dmf"),
    // ...
    STR_PAIR("aif", "audio/aiff"),
};
```

Now, `STR_PAIR` is a preprocessor macro that replaces its arguments with `std::pair<std::string, std::string>(K,V)`, `K` and `V` being the parameters of the macro. For example, the above snippet is no different than:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> mimeMap = {
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("3dm", "x-world/x-3dmf"),
    // ...
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("aif", "audio/aiff"),
};
```

If you're using gcc or clang, you can use `-E` command line option to get preprocessed output and see for yourself. Be aware that it'll be quite big, though.

Finally, such `pair` is used to copy-initialize elements of `mimeMap`.

This code is also buggy, because `map`'s `value_type` is `pair<const Key, Value>`, so `STR_PAIR` should actually create `std::pair<std::string const, std::string>`

Comment: Nice mentioning the _buggy aspect_. +1

Comment: Actually buggy _per se_ or is the conversion guaranteed? (I agree it shouldn't be written this way)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge it is "well-defined" and does (mostly) what the programmer intended, but at the same time `pair<T, T>` and `pair<const T, T>` are distinct types.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can't say much about guarantees, but it definitely results in [different codegen](https://godbolt.org/g/XWziy2) for both clang and gcc across all optimization levels (-Os included). Maybe *buggy* isn't the best word for it? From my perspective paying for unintended consequences of a coding oversight does constitute a bug. But this is an opinion.

Comment: I can get behind that. Was just wondering whether it was a "breaking" bug _per se_ :) FWIW for me this would anyway warrant a ticket in our issue tracking system, albeit at the lowest priority.

Answer (score 1):

From the [reference documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) you have the option to use a `std::initializer_list` constructor (5):

> ```
> map( std::initializer_list<value_type> init,
>      const Compare& comp = Compare(),
>      const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
> ```

the macro builds one from the `std::pair`s and the `#include` directive replaces the text within the `{}` braces. Finally this evaluates to:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> mimeMap = {
    #define STR_PAIR(K,V) std::pair<std::string, std::string>(K,V)
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("3dm", "x-world/x-3dmf"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("3dmf", "x-world/x-3dmf"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("a", "application/octet-stream"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("aab", "application/x-authorware-bin"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("aam", "application/x-authorware-map"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("aas", "a");
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>(pplication/x-authorware-seg"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("abc", "text/vnd.abc"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("acgi", "text/html"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("afl", "video/animaflex"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("ai", "application/postscript"),
    std::pair<std::string, std::string>("aif", "audio/aiff"),    
};
```